# SQL Conditional statement with 2 variables showing unexpected results

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SP that i need to filter based on:

```
....
where 
and cs.chargetype = @chargetype

AND (@chargetype = 'Q' and
    (@biweeklypart = 1 and datepart(dd,cs.scheduledate) = 15)
    OR 
    (@biweeklypart = 1 and datepart(dd,cs.scheduledate) <> 15)
    )
```

But is not working.

What I need is that only when `@chargetype = 'Q'` and `@biweeklypart = 1` then I have to filter by `datepart(dd,cs.scheduledate) = 15`, and if `@chargetype = 'Q'` and `@biweeklypart = 2` then I have to filter by `datepart(dd,cs.scheduledate) <> 15`.

Any clue? I thought I was doing right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description, you want this:

```
where cs.chargetype = @chargetype and
      ( (@chargetype = 'Q' and @biweeklypart = 1 and day(cs.scheduledate) = 15) or 
        (@chargetype = 'Q' and @biweeklypart = 2 and day(cs.scheduledate) <> 15) or
        (@chargetype <> 'Q')
      )
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Gordon,.. was away from the right solution :)

Comment: Gordon I update this question in other post for a more complex thing https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49834270/sql-query-conditional-query-with-acumulated, appreciate so much the help