# SQL Query conditional query with acumulated

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following stored procedure:

```
select
    employeename,
    ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN datepart(mm,cs.scheduledate) = 1 THEN cs.amount ELSE 0 END), 0) as january,
    ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN datepart(mm,cs.scheduledate) = 2 THEN cs.amount ELSE 0 END), 0) as february,
    ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN datepart(mm,cs.scheduledate) = 3 THEN cs.amount ELSE 0 END), 0) as march,
    ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN datepart(mm,cs.scheduledate) = 4 THEN cs.amount ELSE 0 END), 0) as april,
    ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN datepart(mm,cs.scheduledate) = 5 THEN cs.amount ELSE 0 END), 0) as may,
    ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN datepart(mm,cs.scheduledate) = 6 THEN cs.amount ELSE 0 END), 0) as june,
    ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN datepart(mm,cs.scheduledate) = 7 THEN cs.amount ELSE 0 END), 0) as july,
    ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN datepart(mm,cs.scheduledate) = 8 THEN cs.amount ELSE 0 END), 0) as august,
    ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN datepart(mm,cs.scheduledate) = 9 THEN cs.amount ELSE 0 END), 0) as september,
    ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN datepart(mm,cs.scheduledate) = 10 THEN cs.amount ELSE 0 END), 0) as october,
    ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN datepart(mm,cs.scheduledate) = 11 THEN cs.amount ELSE 0 END), 0) as november,
    ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN datepart(mm,cs.scheduledate) = 12 THEN cs.amount ELSE 0 END), 0) as december,
    ISNULL(SUM(cs.amount),0) as a_cds
from 
    statements cs
join
    employee mc on mc.employeeid = cs.employeeid
where 
    cs.chargetype = @chargetype

    -- if @accumulate = 1 then SUM all statement amounts from old months
    and ((datepart(mm, cs.scheduledate) <= @month and @accumulate = 1)
          or (datepart(mm, cs.scheduledate) = @month and @accumulate = 0))

    -- if selection is Biweekly (Q) then filter by that
    and ((@chargetype = 'Q' and @biweeklypart = 1 and day(cs.scheduledate) = 15) or 
         (@chargetype = 'Q' and @biweeklypart = 2 and day(cs.scheduledate) <> 15) or
         (@chargetype <> 'Q')
        )
group by
    employeename
```

Everything works great with this SP but the `Accumulate` filter. It **only works** when `@chargetype` **is not** 'Q'.

So let's look at the following sample data:

[image]

For Employee 15:

- @accumulate = 1
- @month = 2
- @chargetype = 'Q'
- @biweeklypart = 2

I should get the `SUM` of all previous statement records including 02/28/2018. As said this works fine when @chargetype = 'M'.

Any clue?

Comment: Please provide your expected output from given input data.  You are passing @biweeklypart = 2 hence it will return only one row for EmployeeId 15 which is 02/28/2018 based on your where clause condition.

Comment: Change `day(cs.scheduledate) <> 15` to `day(cs.scheduledate) >= 15` this should fix it.